# Deploy java enterprise application on heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have a maven enterprise application **(ejb + war)**, i'm using `glassfish 3.1.2.2`, i have been searching for a way to deploy it on heroku, is there anyway to do this or any documentation that could help?

Comment: Have you walked through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin

Comment: does my answer help you solving your problem?

Comment: yes that helps, i'm trying to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku always has a nice [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin):

Add a pom.xml file to your project

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Create a new heroku app:

```
heroku create
```

> A process type is a command used to start your application. You can
>   configure these with a Procfile as describe in the [Process Types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and
>   the Procfile article. Or you can configure them directly in your
>   pom.xml like this:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
  </processTypes>
</configuration>
```

> If your app is packaged as a WAR, then you can create the slug and
>   deploy it to Heroku with the following command:

```
$ mvn clean heroku:deploy-war
```

> If your application is standalone (and thus required a process type),
>   you can deploy with this command:

```
$ mvn clean heroku:deploy
```